# Is there a list of Stable Widgets?

Tags: flutter

Is there a list of Flutter stable widgets?

I've found several lists of nice flutter widgets, but as many of them have just been released, I'd like to select the stable ones and build over them. This way I'll keep the newer versions for a future version of my App.

Comment: Check out https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets . However, even "stable" widgets could contain bugs/errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to select a specific [Flutter build release channel](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels):

- **`master`** & **`dev`** are probably not what you are looking for as they get updates basically as soon as possible (`dev` only once *fully-tested*)
- **`beta`** has most of the latest functionality but the most stable / *"best [..] build of the previous month"*
- **`stable`**. If you were really concerned, you could choose this, however, this will lack features of the pat few months.

In general, everything that makes it to `beta` has proven to be pretty "stable". Flutter uses [continous integration](https://flutter-dashboard.appspot.com/build.html) and is pretty well-tested.

All of the [*official Flutter* widgets](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets) should work without any issues and if you ever encountered an "unpredictable" bug, you could just open an issue or fix it yourself.

Comment: Thank you. Since the best version of the month is tagged beta, this will be a good choice for my release version.

Comment: @Gorges If you feel like this provides a sufficient answer to your question, you can click the tick mark to indicate to others that this question has an answer.